# Windows XP "open with" not allowing a custom option

Tags: windows-xp, notepad++, file-association, notepad

Up until today I had text files set to open with Notepad++.

Today I moved my Notepad++ installation, and after that I am no longer to use "open with" to get a text file open in Notepad++, even though the program still works fine and I can load a text file by manually launching the program and then doing a File > Open.

If I go to Tools > Folder Options > File Types > Advanced, then I can manually type in the exact path to the executable that I want to use for opening txt files.  However, if I enter the path to Notepad++ and click ok, after closing the window, if I re-open it the field has been automatically restored to reflect the path to standard Windows notepad.

Any ideas?  Never seen anything like this in 10+ years of using XP... :-(

Comment: screen shot and better explanation of "not allowing" please.

Comment: Try adding path to notepad++.exe in environment variable.

Comment: No privileges to do that, unfortunately.  Thanks though.

Comment: Same problem on Windows 7 x64. Cannot open with Notepad++ anymore

Comment: Same problem with Windows 7 x64 - Notepad++ portable. Changed installation directory after associating it with certain file types, and now Open With menu does not show notepad++ even after browsing to its location.

Answer (score 6):

> The program that you're pointing to isn't registered correctly.
>
> In regedit: Navigate to Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications and
>   find your .exe name.  Navigate under its name to shell>open>command.
>   In the Default change its location to the actual location of the
>   executable, hit okay and then try and reassociate the file type as you
>   normally would.

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/problems-with-file-association-in-windows-7-64-bit/8a84fcec-22df-4942-8e35-d98dbe96e327

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have admin privs on the computer in question.  I'm getting around the problem by just not moving the folder.  Actually, that computer has since been upgrade to Win7 (still don't have admin privs), but I put the folder where I wanted it to stay forever, the first time I ran the program. :-)  I'll upvote you because it sounds like good info, but I don't think portable programs should NEED to be registered, that is kind of essential to the portable thing.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks a lot. Your answer helped me with the same issue under Windows 7. Much appreciated!

Comment: Helped me as well, I used to have portable apps on a different drive, seems even trying to set the default to open with the one installed on the right drive didn't update the path.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the direct answer to your problem, but in the past I've used http://download.cnet.com/OpenWith-Enhanced/3000-2094_4-75563165.html to get around some frusterations, and maybe it could work for you as a workaround.